# Javascript: how to assign some specific keys to another object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to create a function where I can pass two objects, one with all keys & other one with only that keys which I want in returned object.

Let's say I have an object:

```
let obj1 = {name: "xx", age: "xx", dateOfBirth: "xx-xx-xxxx" createdAt: "xx-xx-xxxxTxx:xx:xx"};
```

And I want new object with keys,

```
let obj2 = {name: "xx", age: "xx"};
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this please.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Look at destructuring

Comment: `let obj2 = ( ({name, age}) => ({ name, age }) )(obj1);` but you need a comma before createdAt